# WPF initialization issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a class `MyWindow` which inherits from `Window`. Within `MyWindow`, I have the following method to execute once my OK button is clicked:

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var be = NameBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
        this.Close();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="OK" 
        Click="OKButton_Click" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="175,473,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="75" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="-0.04,0.5"/>
```

In a separate class where I initialize my UI window, I say

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow(ViewModel);
window.Show();
```

However, as soon as `window.Show()` is executed, the subsequent code is executed and I cannot actually interact with my window to do what I need to do. I feel like this is just a misunderstanding in how to actually use WPF in a larger context...any help?

Comment: What happens when you call `window.Show()`? Does the UI freeze? Do you get any exceptions or errors in the output window? What is `the subsequent code`?

Comment: Do you need to call [`Window.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) instead? Without knowing more about what the window is supposed to do I hesitate to suggest this as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think what you're looking for is ShowDialog.

Comment: Is it possible that you are forgetting to call InitializeComponent(); in your MainWindow class for the constructor that is accepting a viewmodel as an argument?

Comment: Is `MainWindow` the very first form that should appear as soon as you run your program, or something shown afterwards?

Comment: `Window.ShowDialog()` was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Window.ShowDialog` is what is needed to view the page. But one doesn't get the binding information as you did; which should be changed as well.

When the textbox loses focus it will update the binding so the code

```
 var be = NameBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
 be.UpdateSource();
```

is not needed. (Is this a leftover form winform programming?) So I suggestion one not update a binding as such.

The only possible thing to do if the binding is not updated is to change the binding to use the mode of `TwoWay` which ensures a back and forth data transfer between the variable bound to and the textbox on the screen.